# Сортировка массива структур по полю

Tags: c, сортировка, структуры

Я имею массив инициализированых структур, мне необходимо выполнить простую сортировку по полю (name) в алфавитном порядке. Я знаю,что нужно использовать `qsort()`,но у меня ничего не получается. Помогите пожалуйста написать функцию, которая отсортирует массив `mass`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int my_compare(const void*,const void*);
 typedef struct test{
        char name[100];
        char surname[100];
        char sname[100];
        char posada[100];
        char buff[100];
        int staz;
        char buff2[100];
        int oklad;
        }mass[8]
        ;
int main()
{
   /* struct test{
        char name[100];
        char surname[100];
        char sname[100];
        char posada[100];
        char buff[100];
        int staz;
        char buff2[100];
        int oklad;
        }mass[8]
        ;
        */
    FILE *fo;
    if((fo=fopen("C:\\Users\\andyb\\Desktop\\test2.txt","r"))==NULL)
        printf("error");
    for(int i=1;i<8;i++)
    {
     fgets(mass[i].name,50,fo);
     fgets(mass[i].surname,50,fo);
     fgets(mass[i].sname,50,fo);
     fgets(mass[i].posada,50,fo);
     fgets(mass[i].buff,50,fo);
     mass[i].staz=atoi(mass[i].buff);
     fgets(mass[i].buff2,50,fo);
     mass[i].oklad=atoi(mass[i].buff2);
    }
    fclose(fo);
   for(int i=1;i<8;i++)
    {
    printf("%s%s%s%s%d\n%d\n",mass[i].name,mass[i].surname,mass[i].sname,mass[i].posada,mass[i].staz,mass[i].oklad);
    }
    qsort( mass, sizeof(mass)/sizeof(mass[0]), sizeof(mass[0]), my_compare );
     for(int i=1;i<8;i++)
    {
    printf("%s%s%s%s%d\n%d\n",mass[i].name,mass[i].surname,mass[i].sname,mass[i].posada,mass[i].staz,mass[i].oklad);
    }


    return 0;
}

int my_compare(const void *a,const void *b)
{
    const test *pa = (const test *)pa;
    const test *pb = (const test *)pb;
    /*
        Сравниваем имена и возвращаем 1, 0 или -1, в
        зависимости от результата (без учёта регистра):
    */
    return strcmp( pa->name, pb->name );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Данное объявление `typedef`

```
 typedef struct test{
        char name[100];
        char surname[100];
        char sname[100];
        char posada[100];
        char buff[100];
        int staz;
        char buff2[100];
        int oklad;
        }mass[8]
        ;
```

вводит спецификатор типа `mass` как алиас для типа `struct test[8]`.
Это объявление не создает никакой объект этого типа.

Вам следует написать

```
 typedef struct test{
        char name[100];
        char surname[100];
        char sname[100];
        char posada[100];
        char buff[100];
        int staz;
        char buff2[100];
        int oklad;
        } test;
         ^^^^^^
```

Тогда внутри `main` вы можете объявить массив соответствующего типа следующим образом

```
#define N 8

int main( void )
{
    test mass[N];
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Обратите внимание, что в C функция `main` без параметров объявляется как

```
int main( void )
          ^^^^
```

Кроме того не имеет большого смысла объявлять в структуре члены данных `buff` и `buff2`, чтобы использовать их в качестве буферов для чтения целочисленных членов данных структуры. Вы можете просто завести в main локальную переменную для этих целей, как, например,

```
char buff[100];
```

В этом случае объявление структуры будет выглядеть как

```
 typedef struct test{
        char name[100];
        char surname[100];
        char sname[100];
        char posada[100];
        int staz;
        int oklad;
        } test;
```

Вместо магического числа 8 лучше использовать именованную константу, объявленную как

```
#define N 8
```

или если компилятор поддерживает массивы переменной длины, то как

```
const int N = 8;
```

Индексы массивов в C начинаются с 0. Поэтому данное предложение цикла

```
for(int i=1;i<8;i++)
{
```

неверное. Следует написать

```
for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++ )
{
```

Непонятно также, почему в предложениях, подобных данному

```
fgets(mass[i].name,50,fo);
```

используется магическое число 50, тогда как соответствующий член структуры, объявленный как массив, имеет 100 элементов.

Лучше было бы записать

```
fgets( mass[i].name, sizeof( mass[i].name ), fo );
```

Имейте в виду, что функция `fgets` добавляет символ новой строки в массив, в который она читает данные. Желательно удалить этот символ новой строки из массива. Это можно сделать следующим образом

```
fgets( mass[i].name, sizeof( mass[i].name ), fo );
mass[i].name[strcspn( mass[i].name, "\n" )] = '\0';
```

В функции `my_compare` у вас имеется опечатка:

```
int my_compare(const void *a,const void *b)
{
    const test *pa = (const test *)pa;
                                   ^^^
    const test *pb = (const test *)pb;
                                  ^^^
```

Должно быть

```
int my_compare(const void *a,const void *b)
{
    const test *pa = (const test *)a;
                                   ^^^
    const test *pb = (const test *)b;
                                  ^^^
```

Comment: Все исправил,спасибо за ответ

Answer (score 3):

Прототип `qsort()` выглядит так:

```
void qsort(void *base, size_t nmemb, size_t size,
                  int (*compar)(const void *, const void *));
```

Здесь `base` - указатель на массив, `nmemb` - количество элементов в нём, `size` - размер одного элемента, а `compar` - функция для сравнения элементов. В вашем случае она может выглядеть так:

```
int my_compare( const void * a, const void * b ) {
    /*
       Теперь pa и pb указывают на сравниваемые элементы массива:
    */
    const test *pa = (const test *)a;
    const test *pb = (const test *)b;
    /*
        Сравниваем имена и возвращаем 1, 0 или -1, в
        зависимости от результата (без учёта регистра):
    */
    return strcmp( pa->name, pb->name );
}
```

Итого, вызов может быть таким:

```
qsort( mass, sizeof(mass)/sizeof(mass[0]), sizeof(mass[0]), my_compare );
```

Надеюсь, этой информации хватит чтобы разобраться.

---

Правильный [typedef](http://www.c-cpp.ru/books/typedef):

```
typedef struct {
    char name[100];
    char surname[100];
    char sname[100];
    char posada[100];
    char buff[100];
    int staz;
    char buff2[100];
    int oklad;
} test;

int main()
{
    test mass[8];
}
```

Comment: Проблема в том,что функция не видит структуру,так как она объявлена в функции main()

Comment: и я не могу обращаться к её элементам

Comment: @andybelous, какая функция, почему не видит? Покажите ваш код в вопросе, как всё это выглядит.

Comment: добавил весь текст программы

Comment: @andybelous, не вижу вообще никакой проблемы. Ещё раз внимательно почитайте про работу `qsort`. Ей и не надо "видеть" никакой структуры, достаточно того, что вы передаёте ей первым аргументом указатель на массив структур, который сортируете.

Comment: сравнивающей функции нужно же как-то получать структуру.А у меня структура видна только в мейне

Comment: Да блин. Вы код-то попробуйте сначала написать... Сейчас добавлю в ответ.

Comment: Мне компилятор в этой функции говорит,что он не знает никакого типа данных test.Если я напишу в функции comparator test.name ,то она не поймет о чем я,так как test.name не является глобальной переменной или типом данных

Comment: @andybelous, ну так вынесите определение структуры выше `main()`, делов-то :)

Comment: вынес вверх.Unknown type name test.И это все при том,что я вынес структуру сверху мейн

Comment: ругается на место в функции.где указатель объяв

Comment: обновил текст программы в вопросе

Comment: @andybelous, либо `*pa = (const struct test *)pa`, либо используйте в объявлении структуры [typedef](http://www.c-cpp.ru/books/typedef)

Comment: Использовал typedef,теперь ругаются фунции fgets() too few arguments.*pa = (const struct test *)pa попробовал так,программа выводит содержимое файла и вылетает

Comment: обновил код в вопросе

Comment: @andybelous, потому что typedef неправильный. См. ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Так программа не компилируется. или не работает?

По поводу компиляции Вам уже сказали, как исправить определение типа.

А по поводу работоспособности, у меня вызывает сомнение этот код:

```
const test *pa = (const test *)pa;
const test *pb = (const test *)pb;
```

рискну предположить, что Вы хотели написать:

```
const test *pa = (const test *)a;
const test *pb = (const test *)b;
```